Equilibrium of a lever with non-negligible mass
How does a lever with non-negligible mass behave? How should I go about calculating the torque so that I can write the equilibrium condition?
My idea was to use an integral, that is, if the origin $\ell=0$ is the fulcrum I could integrate along the rod (from $\ell=0$ to $\ell=L_1$), considering that $dm=\rho\,d\ell$:
$$\tau_{\mathrm{tot}} = \int_0^{L_1}\ell\cdot g\,dm=\int_0^{L_1}\ell g\rho\,d\ell$$
for the right arm of the lever, and the same integral from $\ell=-L_2$ to $\ell=0$ for the left arm.
Is this the correct approach?

it depends how rotation axis is positioned along Earth surface. It you rotate lever with an axis which goes along surface normal,- then gravity has nothing to do with your rotation torque. I.e. your torque and gravity induced  torque will be perpendicular to each other  and have no effect upon each other. Otherwise if your torque vector collinear to gravity torque vector, then I think as first approximation is enough to add couple of torques $\tau_{net} = \tau_{ext} + \tau_{gravity}$.  Where gravity torque will act upon lever COM point, so integration is not needed.
